# DataContractJsonSerializer include object name in JSON object

Tags: json, vb.net

I'm trying to serialize a JSON object so I can send it to a web service.  I'm using this asp.net vb code:

```
Dim ser As DataContractJsonSerializer = New DataContractJsonSerializer(postData.GetType())
Dim MS As MemoryStream = New MemoryStream()
ser.WriteObject(MS, postData)
json = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(MS.ToArray())
```

which produces this JSON:

```
{"guid":"10049cf5-a622-4aa6-a1d5-58022c4e2a19"}
```

But what I NEED...is this JSON:

```
{"registerRequest": {"guid":"10049cf5-a622-4aa6-a1d5-58022c4e2a19"}}
```

here is the class definition for the object I'm trying to send:

```
Partial Public Class registerRequest
    Private Property _guid As String
    Public Property guid As String
        Get
            Return _guid
        End Get
        Set(value As String)
            _guid = value
        End Set
    End Property

    Sub New()
    End Sub

End Class
```

How do I get the name of the class to appear in the JSON object as described above?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, to match the format I Just created a wrapper class with a "registerRequest" object inside of it.  Kind of a work around, but it works!

```
Partial Public Class SerializedRegisterRequest
    Private Property _registerRequest As registerRequest
    Public Property registerRequest As registerRequest
        Get
            Return _registerRequest
        End Get
        Set(value As registerRequest)
            _registerRequest = value
        End Set
    End Property

    Sub New()
    End Sub

End Class

Partial Public Class registerRequest
    Private Property _guid As String
    Public Property guid As String
        Get
            Return _guid
        End Get
        Set(value As String)
            _guid = value
        End Set
    End Property

    Sub New()
    End Sub

End Class
```

Answer (score 0):

Add datacontractjsonserializersettings to your constructor on DataContractDataSerializer

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.json.datacontractjsonserializersettings.emittypeinformation.aspx

Try using rootname setting in the constructor instead.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.json.datacontractjsonserializersettings.rootname.aspx

Comment: looks like we're on the right track here, but now I'm ending up with too much data....

    {"__type":"registerRequest:#Qualcomm","guid":"10049cf5-a622-4aa6-a1d5-58022c4e2a19"}

Comment: Try http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.json.datacontractjsonserializersettings.rootname.aspx

Comment: when I try to set a rootname it blows up with: There was an error serializing the object of type Qualcomm.SerializedRegisterRequest. Encountered invalid root element name 'testRootname'. 'root' is the only allowed root element name.  I figured out a workaround below.

Comment: Sorry I could not help.  Most of my experienced is using JSON.NET.